# How to add telemetry data from a video to jpg file?

Tags: ffmpeg, exiftool, telemetry

I have a 360deg video that is created by Go Pro Fusion and has telemetry data in it. I want to extract the telemetry data and put inside of jpg file.

I am extracting images using ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i VIDEO.mp4 -r 5 img%d.jpg
```

How can i extract metadata(including telemetry data) for each frame and put that metadata inside jpg image of that frame.

I tried using

```
exiftool -ee -a -u -U -TagsFromFile video.mp4 img1.jpg
```

But all the metadata that appear in video does not appear in image.

I tried this:

```
exiftool -track1:VideoFrameRate=29.97  img1.jpg
```

But getting this warning:

```
Warning: Sorry, Track1:VideoFrameRate doesn't exist or isn't writable
Nothing to do.
```

```
<Track1:VideoFrameRate>20.00</Track1:VideoFrameRate>
```

I get this from video. But unable to set in jpg as mentioned above.

And how to ensure that the images are assigned with the exact GPS data?

Comment: IMHO, your best chance would be to make it easy for folks to try and help, e.g. share your video (via Dropbox or Google Drive or somesuch) and share the telemetry data that you are hoping to find and which is currently missing.

Comment: Have you tried [exiftool's Inverse Geotagging](https://exiftool.org/geotag.html#Inverse).  Use exiftool to create a GPS track and then geotag using that track.  The major problem would be setting the correct timestamp for each of your extracted images.